# How can I make rl (or prompts) return the value of what the user inputs

Tags: javascript, console.readline

How can I get rl.question to return the value that the user inputs, my code looks like this:

```js
const readline = require('readline');
const { stdin: input, stdout: output } = require('process');
    
const rl = readline.createInterface({ input, output });
    
console.log(rl.question("hello?",(answer) => {return answer}))
```

I know there are probably better modules to use if I want a python-style input function, but 'prompts' seems to have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not super sure what you are asking, so let me know if this isn't it.

[ReadLine Docs](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html)

To `console.log()` the answer from a ReadLine question there are multiple methods, here are some.

try moving the console.log inside of the {}

```js
rl.question('hello? ', (answer) => {
 console.log(answer);
 // ... whatever you want to do with the answer variable 
})
```

or you can use [async/await](https://www.w3docs.com/learn-javascript/async-await.htmlhttps://) with [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```js
async function AskQuestion() {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    rl.question('Hello? ', (answer) => {
      resolve(answer);
    });
  });
}
```

and then just await the function somewhere

```js
(async () => {
    let answer = await AskQuestion();
    console.log(answer);
})();
```